# Do the algebraic real numbers form a complete field?

Tags: real-analysis

It is easy to show that the rational number field is not complete. However, in the classic proof (for example Rudin), the "gaps" are algebraic irrational numbers. Are the transcendental numbers necessary for completion and how can one proof this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by “in the classic proof the gaps are algebraic irrational numbers”, because this is surely false: any complete Archimedean ordered field is isomorphic to the reals, so it contains numbers that are transcendental over the rationals (identified with the prime subfield).

Comment: The completion of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$.  So there is no complete space between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$. It is easy to verify that this sequence is bounded. It does not have a least upper bound in the algebraics, since $e$ is not algebraic.